# computational speed in a for loop

Tags: performance, matlab, random, for-loop, matrix

I have written a small loop in matlab to generate a random NxN matrix. The loop is

```
tic
for i=1:10000
    u=rand(1,10000);
    tau(i,:)=d.*(u(1,:)-0.5);
end
toc
```

I first tried the loop routine only once,

```
    u=rand(1,10000);
    tau=d.*(u(1,:)-0.5);
```

which gave me tau in 0.000169 seconds. I assumed that the loop then would take about 1.69s. It didn't, it took 555.018280s with the fans going wild.

Is there
a) a reason why the speed is not linearly related to the number of iterations?
b) a reason to why it takes **so** much longer to do the routine many times
c) a way to speed this one up (I actually would like to generate larger matrices), for instance a better loop or way to give me, say, a 1'000'000x1'000'000 matrix of the same kind?

Comment: try preallocating `tau`.

Comment: There is a webinar called Speeding up MATLAB Applications. There is some information about large matrices and how to deal with them. https://www.mathworks.com/company/events/webinars/wbnr49643.html?id=49643&p1=961666025&p2=961666043

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have firstly to pre-allocate your matrix `tau`, i.e.

```
  tau = zeros(10000,10000);
```

otherwise matlab will continuously re-allocate it in regions where there is sufficiently free memory (=> find a region with sufficiently free space + hard copy).

In general, you would achieve better performance vectorizing the whole process:

```
 u=rand(10000,10000);
 tau=d.*(u-0.5);
```

---

**EDIT:** Above all, listen to the wise advice of Rody in the comment below. (In any case, I *suppose* that `rand(a,b)` would run a little faster than `a` serial executions of    `rand(1,b)`).

Comment: Better prevent the double-memory allocation (beware, `u` is 800 megabytes): `tau = d.*(rand(10000)-0.5)`. Or, in case `size(d) == [1 10000]`, use `tau = bsxfun(@times, d, rand(10000)-0.5)`. Peak memory will still be the same, however, 800MB of the 1.6GB peak is freed after this allocation. Or: just issue a `clear u` afterwards.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Thus the main point is doing `tau=d.*(rand(10000,10000)-0.5);`, right?. Btw, is `bsxfun` version any faster?

Comment: Probably not faster, but it's useful for when the size of `d` only works with the looped solution (`size(d)==[1 10000]`)

Comment: indeed the tau=d.*(rand(10000,10000)-0.5); made it in 32s, a great improvement! Thanx all!

Answer (score 0):

One obvious possibility is the amount of memory access. The memory for the test loop could have been entirely in cache, but the memory being written by the full loop required a lot of main memory access.

This is a testable hypothesis: Time writing the whole matrix, without doing the arithmetic.

If I understand Matlab indexing, you may be faster switching the dimensions around, so that you write blocks that are in the same column, rather than the same row. Converting u to a column vector outside the loop may also help. In general, large matrix access should be done, as far as possible, in memory order.